# MVVM Light with xamarin binding to ListView

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.android

I have an MVVM Light ViewModel, which has an item inside:

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableKeyValuePair<string, string>> OtherParticipants { get; set; }
```

The item itself is pretty straightforward

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class ObservableKeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    public TValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to bind it to my Xamarin.Android ListView wwith something like this:

```
var vm = VmLocator.Chat;
vm.InitClient(client);
vm.InitModel();

var contactsList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvContacts);

vm.SetBinding(() => vm.OtherParticipants, contactsList.Adapter, BindingMode.TwoWay);
```

The problem is that this line highlights as syntactically incorrect and I am absolutely sure that `contactsList.Adapter` is not the way I can bind my collection to it, but what is the correct way? In addition, how can I define the display member as I can do in WPF. Something like:

```
<ListBox SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding OtherParticipants}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParticipant}" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
```

Comment: Can you show an example or a screenshot in regards to "The problem is that this line highlights as syntactically incorrect", that statement makes it kinda hard to help you.

Comment: It's not really that relevant, I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something generally wrong in terms of making this work, so what I really need here is an example how to do that or a guidline regarding to how this is exactly done against Androids ListView

Comment: It actually is relevant.  It's why no one's answered.  At least give a screenshot of what you expect or want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a working answer for this problem.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MainChat);

    var client = Nav.GetAndRemoveParameter<MyClient>(Intent);

    var vm = VmLocator.Chat;
    vm.InitClient(client);
    vm.InitModel();

    var contactsList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lvContacts);

    contactsList.Adapter = vm.OtherParticipants.GetAdapter(ContactsListViewTemplate);
}

private View ContactsListViewTemplate(int position, ObservableKeyValuePair<string, string> participant,
    View convertView)
{
    var view = convertView ?? LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ParticipantsListItem, null);

    var firstName = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tvParticipantName);

    firstName.Text = participant.Value;

    return view;
}
```

The valuable part of this are the last 2 lines of `OnCreate` method. I've found the answer [here](https://mallibone.com/post/mvvm-light-listview-bindings-android)